# How to work with two columns containing different GetSelectLink method in the same WebGrid?

Tags: webgrid

I am a beginner in ASP.Net MVC3 and trying implement a table using WebGrid I faced off with a problem.

In an row of this table I have "Id" and "Name" (came from DB) and two links more: "Edit" and "Delete". These links are executed using item.GetSelectLink() inside the same web grid, as follows:

```
<div id="grid">
    @{
        var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, rowsPerPage: 30, canPage: true, canSort: true, fieldNamePrefix: "gridDivisoes_", selectionFieldName: "Id");
    }

    @grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "table", headerStyle: "header", footerStyle: "footer", alternatingRowStyle: "alternate",
    columns: grid.Columns(
                grid.Column("Name", header: "Division", style: "text-align-left", canSort: true),
                grid.Column(header: "Update?", style: "text-align-center", format: (item) => item.GetSelectLink("[update]")),
                grid.Column(header: "Delete?", style: "text-align-center", format:(item) => item.GetSelectLink("[delete]"))
            ))   

        if(grid.HasSelection)
        {
            if("[delete]" == grid. ????) //click's origin: "[delete]"
            {
                <input type="hidden" value="@Html.AttributeEncode(Model.ElementAt(grid.SelectedIndex).Id)" id="Id" name="Id" />
                <input type="hidden" value="@Html.AttributeEncode(Model.ElementAt(grid.SelectedIndex).Name)" id="Name" name="Name" />

                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <p>Do you really want to delete the division "@Model.ElementAt(grid.SelectedIndex).Name" ?</p>
                <p><input type="submit" value="Delete" /></p>
            }

            if ("[update]" == grid. ????) //click's origin: "[update]"
            {
                <input type="hidden" value="@Html.AttributeEncode(Model.ElementAt(grid.SelectedIndex).Id)" id="Id" name="Id" />

                <div class="editor-label">
                    Name
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(Page => Page.ElementAt(grid.SelectedIndex).Name)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Page => Page.ElementAt(grid.SelectedIndex).Name)
                </div>        
                <br />
                <br />
                <p><input type="submit" value="Update"/></p>
            }
        }
</div>
```

How could I get the click's origin and execute the grid.HasSelection accordingly "Delete" or "Update" options?
I can't believe that there I can't choose one between these options, select a row and, at same time, just to know the click origin.

How could I do a comparison? Something like that   *if("[delete]" == grid. ????)*  ?

Answer (score 1):

Amanda, if i understood you correctly, you want to be able to both edit and delete a row, right?

If so, you can try this:

```
columns: grid.Columns(
                grid.Column("Name", header: "Division", style: "text-align-left", canSort: true),
                grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Update?", "Update", new { updateId = item.ID })),
                        grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Delete?", "Update", new { deleteId = item.ID }))
            ))
```

You can even use Ajax to render a partial with your row values, if you like